# how to remove a part of the url using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

If there is a url where i need to remove the timestamp part of it. How would i do it in javascript.

Regex or string operations which is preferred?

Here is the url ,

```
"%7B%22def%22%3A%22f%3Ar%22%2C%22a%22%3A%7B%22v%22%3A%7B%22r%22%3A%22005x0000001R9JRAA0%22%7D%7D%2C%22t%22%3A1378328815840%7D"
                                                                                                      ^
```

`t%22%3A1378328815840%7D`, this is what i need to remove from the url, it is the timestamp.

Comment: t%22%3A1378328815840%7D, this is what i need to remove from teh url, it is the timestamp

Comment: You want to actual remove that part from the `url`, or retrieve the `url` in a `string` and then edit that `string` ? In both cases, a simply look over https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace should make it clear.

Comment: i need to remove that part from teh existing url

Comment: The `%7D` is a close bracket in most character sets, and probably corresponds to the `%7B` at the start of the input, so is probably not part of the timestamp.  Are you sure you want to remove it too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this encodes a JSON string

> ```
> {"def":"f:r","a":{"v":{"r":"005x0000001R9JRAA0"}},"t":1378328815840}
> ```

you can do

```
function removeTimestamp(uriStr) {
  // Decode the JSON encoded in the URI.
  var jsonObj = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(uriStr));
  // Remove the "t" property.
  delete jsonObj['t'];
  // Re-encode as a URI-encoded JSON string
  return encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
}
```

---

On your input string,

```
var s = "%7B%22def%22%3A%22f%3Ar%22%2C%22a%22%3A%7B%22v%22%3A%7B%22r%22%3A%22005x0000001R9JRAA0%22%7D%7D%2C%22t%22%3A1378328815840%7D"

var sWithoutTimestamp = removeTimestamp(s);

alert(sWithoutTimestamp);
```

yields the first line below.  I've put a gap where the timestamp part was so you can easily compare it to the original.

```
Modified: %7B%22def%22%3A%22f%3Ar%22%2C%22a%22%3A%7B%22v%22%3A%7B%22r%22%3A%22005x0000001R9JRAA0%22%7D%7D                          %7D
Original: %7B%22def%22%3A%22f%3Ar%22%2C%22a%22%3A%7B%22v%22%3A%7B%22r%22%3A%22005x0000001R9JRAA0%22%7D%7D%2C%22t%22%3A1378328815840%7D
```

---

JavaScript doesn't specify key iteration order, and `JSON.stringify`'s output depends on key iteration order, so on some interpreters you might see reordering of properties, but it shouldn't affect the meaning of the output.

---

This code also might also do strange things if the URI is not UTF-8 encoded and contains non-ASCII code-points.